# How to get results of tasks when they finish and not after all have finished in Dask?

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

I have a dask dataframe and want to compute some tasks that are independent. Some tasks are faster than others but I'm getting the result of each task after longer tasks have completed.

I created a local Client and use `client.compute()` to send tasks. Then I use `future.result()` to get the result of each task.

I'm using threads to ask for results at the same time and measure the time for each result to compute like this:

```py
def get_result(future,i):
    t0 = time.time()
    print("calculating result", i)
    result = future.result()
    print("result {} took {}".format(i, time.time() - t0))

client = Client()
df = dd.read_csv(path_to_csv)

future1 = client.compute(df[df.x > 200])
future2 = client.compute(df[df.x > 500])

threading.Thread(target=get_result, args=[future1,1]).start()
threading.Thread(target=get_result, args=[future2,2]).start()
```

I expect the output of the above code to be something like:

```
calculating result 1
calculating result 2
result 2 took 10
result 1 took 46
```

Since the first task is larger.

But instead I got both at the same time

```
calculating result 1
calculating result 2
result 2 took 46.3046760559082
result 1 took 46.477620363235474
```

I asume that is because *future2* actually computes in the background and finishes before *future1*, but it waits until *future1* is completed to return.

Is there a way I can get the result of future2 at the moment it finishes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to make threads to use futures in an asynchronous fashion - they are already inherently async, and monitor their status in the background. If you want to get results in the order they are ready, you should use [`as_completed`](https://distributed.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#distributed.as_completed).

However, fo your specific situation, you may want to simply view the dashboard (or use `df.visulalize()`) to understand the computation which is happening. Both futures depend on reading the CSV, and this one task will be required before either can run - and probably takes the vast majority of the time. Dask does not know, without scanning all of the data, which rows have what value of `x`.